# rplidar_node on ros2 / Autoware drops message in rviz2 for ‚Unknown‘ reason

Tags: ros, ros2

I‘m using [Autoware](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto) in its most recent version on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine and this [rplidar_node](https://github.com/youtalk/rplidar_ros). The node publishes correct messages when I check with `ros2 topic echo scan` but it fails to get them shown on rviz2 with this error message

`[INFO] [1625892725.336256970] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1625892723.515 for reason 'Unknown'`

When I use ros melodic everything works fine.

Comment: The problem is your tf tree. Make sure you have a transform from your `fixed Frame` in rviz to the `laser_frame`